# Which data structure should I use for a hash without values?

Tags: perl, data-structures, hash

I need to check if a scalar exists in a set of scalars. What is the best way of storing this set of scalars?

Walking through an array would yield linear check time. The check time for a hash would be constant, but it feels inefficient since I wouldn't be using the value part of the hash.

Comment: @Mark: I figure there should be a structure that is strictly better than using a hash, probably with the same time complexity but better space complexity.

Comment: @Mark: It is static, so I'll never change it. ~1000 elements, but I'm also interested in the asymptotic complexity.

Comment: Why are you interested in asymptotic complexity (how something scales) if the number of elements never changes.

Comment: @ikegami: The number never changes within the program. The asymptotic complexity probably won't matter, but I'm curious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a hash, but don't use the values.  There really isn't a better way.

Comment: Is this true for Perl or for data structures in general?

Comment: For Perl; I'm sure at least some languages provide a type more customized to this purpose.

Comment: In the case of a language like Java, you would utilize a HashSet. However, in Perl you could just not use the values, or store how many times the value has appeared (if it could appear more than once that is).

Answer (score 5):

The memory overhead for using a hash to test for set membership is minimal, and greatly outweighs the cost of repeated sequential searches through an array.  There are many ways to make a set membership style hash:

```
my %set = map {$_ => 1} ...;

my %set; $set{$_}++ for ...;

my %set; @set{...} = (1) x num_of_items;
```

Each of these allows you to use the hash lookup directly in a conditional without any additional syntax.

If your hash is going to be huge, and you are worried about the memory usage, you can store `undef` as the value for each key.  But in that case you will have to use `exists $set{...}` in your conditionals.

Comment: in modern perls, an integer or a reference is just as cheap as undef

Answer (score 5):

A hash should do fine. You could use undef for the value and use `exists($h{$k})` or you could use `1` and use `$h{$k}`.

[Judy::HS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Judy%3a%3aHS) should be a bit more efficient, but there's no value-less version of that structure either.

Answer (score 1):

You may find this section of the FAQ useful:

[How can I tell whether a certain element is contained in a list or array?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-tell-whether-a-certain-element-is-contained-in-a-list-or-array?)

Comment: I read it already, and it doesn't seem to contain any suggestions other than looping through an array or checking a hash (or even looping through a hash!).

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through an array could be done:

```
my @arr = ( $list, $of, $scalars );
push @arr, $any, $other, $ones;
```

It's expensive to look through, but not that expensive unless you have a massive list:

```
grep { $_ eq $what_youre_looking_for } @arr;
```

The hash method also works:

```
my %hash = ( $list => 1, $of => 1, $scalars => 1 );
$hash{$another} = 1;

if ( exists $hash{$what_youre_looking_for} ) {
    ...
}
```

You could implement a binary search and a list sorter, but those are the two most used methods.

Comment: Yes, those are the methods I mentioned in my question. I was wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

HashTable is the best option.

Note:- As you said it is a set, I hope there are no duplicate elements.